# How to change a text based onclick with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Good evening everybody!

Well, I am studying JavaScript at the moment, and I reachead the point in where I need, based on clicked text (button, ... it doesn't matter, I guess).

For example:

> This message should be edited.

Two choices: ES - EN

If choice "ES" is clicked/selected, then:

> This message has been edited to ES.

Otherwise, if choice "EN" is clicked/selected, then:

> This message has been edited to EN.

I think this could have been achieved with an if in a script, but the problem is how to tell the script which option has been chosen, if "ES" or "EN".

I have this:

```
<p id="demo">This message should be edited.<p>
<a href="#" id="ES" onclick="func();">ES</a> - <a href="#" id="EN" onclick="func();">EN</a> - <a href="#" id="JP" onclick="func();">JP</a>
```

And as I said, the problem is that I don't know how to tell the script what has been clicked/selected.

Thank you for any help you may give me (if possible, an explanation with or over a solution would be amazing because I want to learn and understand, not to solve this problem without being able to solve the same thing or similar in a future).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a argument to the function for example

```
function fun(lang){
    If(lang === "ES"){
        Do something 
    }else If(lang === "EN"){
        Do something 
    }
}
```

And when you call your function put something like this:

onClick="fun('ES')" or onClick="fun('EN')

NOTE: instead of If 's you could use switch statement inside your function fun(lang)

Comment: This really did the trick and was what I was looking for. I was looking to pass an argument so the if could have a correct comparison. The problem was that how'd I pass an argument, and the answer was with "fun('ES')", which 'ES' was my mistake because I didn't put it there. So bad from me! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Pass `this` to you function for get clicked element.

Then set it's `id` to you `p` tag using [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp).

See e.g.

```js
function func(ele){
    var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
    demo.innerHTML = "This message should be edited to "+ele.id+".";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">This message should be edited.<p>
<a href="#" id="ES" onclick="func(this);">ES</a> - <a href="#" id="EN" onclick="func(this);">EN</a> - <a href="#" id="JP" onclick="func(this);">JP</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass `this` in your `func()`, this will allow you to access the current clicked element.

```js
var text = "This message should be edited to ";
function func(ele){
  console.log(ele.innerHTML);
  document.getElementById('demo').innerText = text + ele.innerText + ".";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">This message should be edited.<p>
<a href="#" id="ES" onclick="func(this);">ES</a> - <a href="#" id="EN" onclick="func(this);">EN</a> - <a href="#" id="JP" onclick="func(this);">JP</a>
```

Comment: This could work if the intention was just to change a number of parts, but, if in my case (that I didn't specify, sorry about that!), I want to use it as a multilingual script. For example, change the full language of an html from EN to ES. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var text = 'This message has been edited to ';

function func(e){
 document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = text+e.id+'.'; 
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">This message should be edited.<p>
<a href="#" id="ES" onclick="func(this);">ES</a> - <a href="#" id="EN" onclick="func(this);">EN</a> - <a href="#" id="JP" onclick="func(this);">JP</a>
```

you can pass `this` which works as an clicked event, from there get value and add to your result

Comment: Thank you but what Jiovani said was what I was looking for. This could work, anyways!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Using JavaScript

// Firstly we get the demo element
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");

// When an element on the document si clicked
document.onclick = function(event) 

// if the target element has an id of "ES" change demo content to spanish
    if (event.target.id == "ES") {
    demo.innerHTML = "Spanish or EspagnolText";

  } else if (event.target.id == "EN") {

// else if element has an id of "EN" change demo content to english
    demo.innerHTML = "English Text";
  }
}
```

Comment: This could also work, but I think it's easier to do the way Jovani explained. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Another way using Switch Case.

**HTML:**

```
<p id="demo">This message should be edited.<p>
<a href="#" id="ES" onclick="func(this.id);">ES</a> - <a href="#" id="EN" onclick="func(this.id);">EN</a> - <a href="#" id="JP" onclick="func(this);">JP</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var text = 'This message has been edited to ';

function func(value) {
  var selectValue="";

    switch (value) {
      case "EN":
          selectValue = "EN";
        break;

        case "ES":
            selectValue = "ES";
        break;

        case "JP":
            selectValue = "JP";
        break;
}

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = text + selectValue + '.';
}
```

Note: [Anchor Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)  tag defines a hyperlink, which is used to link from one page to another.